# Set static position View inside Tableview (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, addsubview

Currently I'm passing all my storyboard viewcontrollers to code, And currently I've encountered a visual issue. That for some reason does not replicate on my code addSubView()

This is how it looks on my Storyboard

[image]

this is the code that appends the View inside the tableview

```
let profileView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,500,45))
    profileView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.35, green:0.77, blue:0.66, alpha:1)
    self.tableview.addSubview(profileView)
```

The issue is that with this code the view scrolls the view as I go up or down, and with the Storyboard VC, it only scrolls the Tableview and my view simply stays static on the position I placed it and that is the way i like it to be. "static"

[image]

This also ilustrates what I want to achieve.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I threw this together for you. It's an example of how to do it. However the UITableview was not intended to be used this way. You can see that the cell 0 is covered by your custom view. You will have to take that into account when filling the tableview from your datasource.

```
    import UIKit

class testTableVIewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet var theTableView: UITableView!
    var profileView:UIView

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    profileView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,500,45))
    profileView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.35, green:0.77, blue:0.66, alpha:1)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.theTableView.addSubview(profileView)
    
}
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    profileView.frame = CGRectOffset( profileView.frame, scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0 );
    
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = theTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row)
        return cell!
    }
}
```

[image]

instead of putting the view as a sub view of the table view what you should do is.

1. create a view. (i will call this content view for convenience)
2. add the view to this the content view.
3. add the tableview to the content view.

just position the view/table view next to each other inside the content view.
this will have the desired effect of a scrolling table view and a static view next to each other. reverse step 2&3 if the desired effect is a floating view over the tableview.

Oh btw. Changing to that kind of layout is pretty easy if you are doing it all in code. Just change your tableview controller to a view controller and adopt the UITablview Protocols.

```
class testTableVIewController: UITableViewController {
class testTableVIewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
```

then add a property for a tableview class. Also add it to self.view in the correct position. also remember to add your green view to self.view

if you do it like that you won't have to change much code at all.

Comment: Not the answer I'm looking for, since it will force me to create a Viewcontroller and change most of my current logic. There should be a easier way of doing this since UITableviewController and not a UIViewController.

Comment: What you are looking to do is a actually harder. You will need to keep track of the scroll position and move the view as the table view scrolls. Use scrollViewDidScroll for that. It actually is very little code to change to do it the way I'm saying.

Comment: Does not matter. The same ideas apply. You are using the same class objects. just adding them to the screen differently.

Comment: You can also see I added your green box using your own code. Just moved it to a property so it can be accessed in scrollViewDidScroll

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111151/discussion-between-kent-and-eddwinpaz).